# In Visual Studio how can I get a new test which I have added to a test project to appear in the Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, testing

I have an existing solution that includes a test project. I added a new test to an existing test class and it works fine. However, logically that test should be in a class of its own. I create a new test class with all the correct decoration but I cannot get it to appear in Test Explorer. VS 2022 Community

Any Suggestions